# Using Low Events with Structure

Tags: structure, low-events

I'm using Low Events and Structure on a site. I have setup the Calendar tag on a template that is displaying dynamic content from another channel. On the main calendar page, there is only one segment in the URL and the dynamic content displays correctly. When I add a date to the second segment, the dynamic content displays incorrectly (displays content from another entry).

I'm wondering if and how I can get Low Events and Structure to work together so that users can change the month in the calendar and still correctly display the content from the other channel on the same template. Thanks.

EE 2.8.1
LE 1.3.0

Comment: I've used Low Events and Structure on the same site. You need to use Freebie.

Comment: Oh, right!. I had that thought (but lost that thought at some point). Thanks, I'll give it a shot.